# Time management app with scheduling

Tags: osx, ios, time-management, macos, planning

I'm looking for a free application to manage my time.

The requirements are the following:

- **Adding tasks** without specifying when I'll be working on them

  - Ability to add some basic info about the task, such as the length of the task, ...
- **Planning feature** - dragging those created tasks to the calendar
- **Predefined tasks** for the day repeated every week (sleep, school, meals, ...)

---

Good to have:

- Ability to mark tasks as completed
- There should be also support for overlapping tasks
- Both desktop (macOS is enough) and mobile (iOS is also enough) should be supported

  - Or it can be just a web-based application
- The UI should be simple and intuitive

Do you, guys, know such an app?